# Href link not display in Gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, http

In my Rails application, I am sending email to users where in my one `email` use  link which one is `not display LINK in gmail` but in my `default mailer` its work fine.

## Below link is used in email

```
<a href="lina://lina.app.com">Click here to active</a>
```

If i used `http://` instead of `lina://` then its works fine.

Why this `not appear link in gmail`. Its simple display "Click here to active" without link in Gmail.

I tried lots but not getting proper solutions.

Any one have a trick? Thanks

Comment: Why would you want that? Gmail is probably filtering out illegal links

Answer (score 0):

The http is a protocol.  IANA is responsible for defining valid protocols.  Here is there list:

[IANA protocols](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml)

Since lana is an invalid protocol, GMail does the users the favor of filtering out the invalid link.  This is by design, and until IANA approves the protocol, GMail will filter it out.  Send IANA a request to publish an RFC for the protocol you wish to establish at:

[Apply for a protocol assignment](http://www.iana.org/protocols/apply)

In the mean time, use the http, or protocol-less assignment:

```
<a href="//lina.app.com">register</a>
```